# How to create Angular custom elements with Angular universal: SSR

Tags: angular, angular-universal, angular-elements

I am trying to create an Angular app with [Angular Universal: SSR](https://angular.io/guide/universal) and [Custom Elements](https://angular.io/guide/elements).

I downloaded the sample code available in [Angular Universal: SSR](https://angular.io/guide/universal) and added the following lines of code to for *Custom Elements* in **AppModule**'s constructor

```
const ele = createCustomElement(AppComponent, {injector});
customElements.define('custom-ele', ele);
```

It is building just fine, but when I try to serve it I am getting the following error

```
...universal\dist\server.js:66760
var elProto = Element.prototype;

ReferenceError: Element is not defined
at Object.<anonymous> (...universal\dist\server.js:66760:15)
at __webpack_require__ (...universal\dist\server.js:20:30)
....
```

Is it because *Element* is a browser-only native objects, and since its on Server Side it won't be able reference browser-only native objects? Is there a work around?

Answer (score 6):

You're right, Angular Elements aren't supported by Angular Universal yet. The error is due to this import:

```
import {createCustomElement} from '@angular/elements';
```

In the meanwhile, there's a workaround you can use, you can conditionally import
`createCustomElement` in this way:

After your imports just declare the `require`:

```
declare var require: any;
```

Then use the `isPlatformBrowser` method from `@angular/common` to import createCustomElement only in the client:

```
if (isPlatformBrowser(platformId)) {
  const { createCustomElement } = require('@angular/elements');
  // you can use createCustomElement here
}
```